# Erro limit Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Olá pessoal do Codeigniter Brasil,
Eu estou com uma query que retorna tudo perfeito no localhost mas no servidor não retorna da forma que foi escrita.

É para retornar 6 resultados mas no servidor retorna a quantidade que ele achar melhor até 6.

```
$this->db->limit(6);
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("vips");
$this->db->join("anuncios", "anuncios.id = vips.idPostVip");
$this->db->order_by('RAND()');
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Alguma dica ?

Alguma configuração do PHP ?

Me ajudem Rs.

Obrigado.

Comment: qual é o resultado esperado com esse código, quantos registros deveriam retornar?

Comment: Deveriam retornar 3 resultados.

Comment: Então o limite ele está respeitando se trás 1, 2 ou 3. Deve ser esse where vip > 0. Verifique os dados. Não devem estar atendendo o where.

Comment: Olá, então no servidor tem muitos posts vips, ele puxa só os vips mas não trás os 3 que eu preciso.
É isso que não estou entendendo.

Comment: Eu colocaria a linha do limit depois do order_by, mas não sei se isso é o problema.

Comment: @BrunoLuiz já tentou tirar a linha `$this->db->where("vip > ",0);` para ver se funciona?

Comment: Já tirei e continua igual rs.

Comment: Poxa então precisa ver todo o processo para termos certeza do que está acontecendo ... complicado mesmo

Comment: Oque me deixa sem entender é que só tenho o model, puxo no Controller e exibo na View, não tem mais nada.
Será que tem outra forma de fazer random sem order by ?

Comment: Tem sim! .... ....

Comment: Este post não foi respondido aqui e não foi respondido aqui.
Ficam colocando que meu post foi resolvivo aqui mas não foi, as respostas foram erradas e eu continuo com o problema.

Comment: Quando vc roda essa consulta direto no banco (via phpmyadmin) do servidor de produção vem 6 registros?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize dessa forma:

```
public function exibeSugestaoHome()
{
    $this->db->limit(3);
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("anuncios");
    $this->db->where("vip > ",0);
    $this->db->order_by('RAND()');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

pode ser feito assim também, fazendo o embaralhamento de itens pela função do [php](/questions/tagged/php), [**shuffle**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php):

```
public function exibeSugestaoHome()
{
    $this->db->limit(3);
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("anuncios");
    $this->db->where("vip > ",0);
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    shuffle($result);
    return $result;
}
```

a diferença das formas apresentadas que a primeira embaralha os itens direto na tabela, e o segundo somente nos resultados obtidos. Dependendo da situação uma delas se encaixa.

Comment: Pior que acabei de perceber que não funcionou, a última opção puxa os três e embaralha somente.
Eu preciso puxar itens aleatórios do banco para não ficar repetindo.

Comment: Verdade @BrunoLuiz o ultimo ele pega os 3 e gera um embaralhamento desses itens, já o primeiro gera o embaralhamento nos dados da tabela. Talvez tenha algo na sua tabela que está ocasionando ou na SQL que não está trazendo os 3 itens, tem que ver a fundo.

Comment: Então, no banco a opção vip é 0 ou 1.

Comment: @BrunoLuiz, então remova essa linha `$this->db->where("vip > ",0);` não faz sentido ou pior não recomendo `$this->db->where("vip >= ",0);` que é a mesma coisa que a primeira

Comment: Mas este campo eu só posso puxar os carros que são patrocinados no site, ali eu marco eles como patrocinado "vip" ou não.

Comment: @BrunoLuiz se vip é igual = 1 coloque `$this->db->where("vip",1);` ou o valor correspondente?